# Fatal error: Call to a member function sayHello() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php

Tags: magento-1.9

test.php

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::init();

$product=new TutsPlus_Demo_Model_Product;
$product->sayHello();

$product1 = Mage::getModel("demo/product");
 $product1->sayHello();

echo get_class($product1);
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <demo>
                <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Model</class> 
            </demo>
        </models>
    </global>
 </config>
```

product.php

```
<?php

class TutsPlus_Demo_Model_Product{

    public function sayHello(){

        echo "Hello Hi how are you"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the declaration file `app/etc/modules/TutsPlus_Demo.xml` ?

Comment: @Marius : should it be `Mage::app()` instead of `Mage::init()` ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt. I usually use `Mage::app()`.

Comment: @Marius : you mean `Mage::init()` also work ? I am also normally using `Mage::app()`

Comment: @programmer_rkt. I didn't try it, but it should work. It is used in `api.php` and `get.php`.

Answer (score 4):

Try below things.

1. As marius commented out, make sure the activation file exist

File : `app/etc/modules/TutsPlus_Demo.xml` and its content should be

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TutsPlus_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2. Make sure the model path looks like this. Beware capital letters

File : `app/code/local/TutsPlus/Demo/Model/Product.php`

3. At last, try to use `Mage::app()` instead of `Mage::init()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, But I think you should use

```
Mage::app();
```

Instead of

```
Mage::init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change

> Mage::init()

to

> Mage::run()

Comment: Maybe add some more information as to why to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try these which worked for me:

1. Please don't use capital letters in XML nodes/tags in config.xml
   file.
2. Remove `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` in config.xml
3. it looks like you saved as product.php, make  "P" caps because "TutsPlus_Demo_Model_Product". your class is defined in **Product.php**
   file.

Comment: I *personally* disagree with point 1 and 2 here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. If the module class was recently instantiated do the following:

1. Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage
2. Delete the contents of var/cache folder
3. Try again

Hope this works for you.